# Display Post Type taxonomy categories

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, categories, taxonomy

im really struggling to find clear documentation on the following subject.

- I have created a custom post type called '**file**'.
- List item I've also created a   taxonomy called '**file_category**'

From the WordPress Admin i've created categories: *Configs, Media, Demos, SourceTV*

- I have a page using a template to display a list of all the '**file**' posts.
- I want to then display a list of the categories so users can filter the '**file**' results.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to post your replies!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, those "file_category" categories you created are called "Terms", so if you want to edit your template file to show the "file_category" terms for each post, you would use get_the_terms() inside the loop. Documentation is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

To show all terms in a taxonomy (like the list of terms you mentioned you wanted to display) use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Comment: Thanks so much mate, I found everything i needed here; http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Examples